# Return Pandas dataframe from PostgreSQL query with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to query a PostgreSQL database and return the output as a Pandas dataframe.

I created a connection to the database with 'SqlAlchemy':

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost:5432/mydb')
```

I write a Pandas dataframe to a database table:

```
i=pd.read_csv(path)
i.to_sql('Stat_Table',engine,if_exists='replace')
```

Based on the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html), looks like pd.read_sql_query() should accept a SQLAlchemy engine:

```
a=pd.read_sql_query('select * from Stat_Table',con=engine)
```

But it throws an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "stat_table" does not exist
```

I'm using Pandas version 0.14.1.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You are bitten by the case (in)sensitivity issues with PostgreSQL. If you quote the table name in the query, it will work:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "Stat_Table"',con=engine)
```

But personally, I would advise to just always use lower case table names (and column names), also when writing the table to the database to prevent such issues.

---

From the PostgreSQL docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case

To explain a bit more: you have written a table with the name `Stat_Table` to the database (and sqlalchemy will quote this name, so it will be written as "Stat_Table" in the postgres database). When doing the query `'select * from Stat_Table'` the unquoted table name will be converted to lower case `stat_table`, and so you get the message that this table is not found.

See eg also [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Answer (score 23):

Late to the party here, but to give you a full example of this:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2 as pg

engine = pg.connect("dbname='my_db_name' user='pguser' host='127.0.0.1' port='15432' password='pgpassword'")
df = pd.read_sql('select * from Stat_Table', con=engine)
```

You need to run the following to install the dependencies for ubuntu:

```sh
pip install pandas psycopg2-binary SQLAlchemy
```

Pandas docs on the subject [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 22):

Read postgres sql data in pandas in given below and image link

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql
connection = pg.connect("host=localhost dbname=kinder user=your_username password=your_password")
dataframe = psql.read_sql('SELECT * FROM product_product', connection)
product_category = psql.read_sql_query('select * from product_category', connection)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bege.png

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that a table named:

```
stat_table
```

does not exist( a *relation* is a table in postgres speak).  So, of course you can't select rows from it.  Check your db after executing:

```
i.to_sql('Stat_Table',engine,if_exists='replace')
```

and see if a table by that name got created in your db.

When I use your read statement:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from Stat_Table',con=engine)
```

I get the data back from a postgres db, so there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks. Checked and the table was indeed created. Like @joris said, it was a case sensitivity problem in table name: I re-wrote the table: `i.to_sql('stat_table',engine,if_exists='replace')` and then it works: `a=pd.read_sql_query('select * from stat_table',engine)`

Comment: @Imart999, When I wrote: **see if a table by that name got created in your db** --**that name** was referring to the name in the error message, which was `stat_table`.  The error message name is what is relevant--with ANY error you get.  And because python NEVER makes a mistake, the error meant your code NEVER created a table named `stat_name`.  See how I posted the table name `stat_name` in it's own paragraph and highlighted it--that was supposed to direct your attention to it.

Comment: Right, I get it. I saw both responses at the same time (was offline). I see that your response is leading me to the same answer (e.g., ensure table named `stat_table` is written) that @joris stated explicitly (e.g., case sensitivity matters). Appreciate the response.

Comment: @Imart999, No worries.  When I reread my answer, I realized that what `that name` referred to wasn't entirely clear.  I should have left out your line of code.

Answer (score 1):

import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user@localhost:5432/mydb')

You must specify **schema and table**
df = pd.read_sql_query("""select * from "dvd-rental".film""", con=engine)