# Is there a way to run posqresql queries in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe like this :

|  | created_at | lat | long | hex_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-10-13 15:12:18.682905 | 28.690628 | 77.323285 | 883da1ab0bfffff |
| 1 | 2020-10-12 22:49:05.886170 | 28.755408 | 77.112289 | 883da18e87fffff |
| 2 | 2020-10-13 15:24:17.692375 | 28.690571 | 77.323335 | 883da1ab0bfffff |
| 3 | 2020-10-12 23:21:13.700226 | 28.589922 | 77.082738 | 883da112a1fffff |
| 4 | 2020-10-13 15:43:58.887592 | 28.649227 | 77.339063 | 883da1a941fffff |

and I want to convert it like this

|  | created_at | hex_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-10-28 22:00:00 | 883da11185fffff | 4 |
| 1 | 2020-09-09 10:00:00 | 883da111ebfffff | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-12-02 20:00:00 | 883da10769fffff | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-10-16 07:00:00 | 883da111c3fffff | 1 |
| 4 | 2020-12-13 11:00:00 | 883da11747fffff | 4 |

As of now i am taking the dataframe dumping it into postgres and running the below query and then exporting data and at last importing back to my notebook .

Query :

```
SELECT created_at('hour', timestamp),count(lat),hex_id FROM public."ML_Data"
group by created_at('hour', timestamp),hex_id
```

I was wondering if I could directly do it in the notebook file

Comment: maybe look into `pd.read_sql`?

Comment: or you can simply do a pd.DataFrame.groupby instead of dumping it into postgres for aggregations.

Comment: @ABC i tried pd.read_Sql but i dont think above query will run on it and group by is okay but i want the dataframe in a particular format , is there any code for referrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use groupy in df.

```py
# 2020-10-13 15:12:18.682905 -> 2020-10-13 15:00:00
df['created_at_n'] = df['created_at'].astype(str).str.split(':').str[0] + ':00:00'
df.groupby(['created_at_n', 'hex_id'])['lat'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use `psycopg2` for fetching data from postgres, an example code:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

with psycopg2.connect(
        host='your_host',
        database='your_database',
        user='your_username',
        password='your_password') as con: 

    cursor = con.cursor()

    query = sql.SQL('your_query_string')
    cursor.execute(query)
    
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names) # your data column names
```

or i think you could `pd.read_sql`, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884268/return-pandas-dataframe-from-postgresql-query-with-sqlalchemy).

Comment: let me share a bit more insight on my data , I have connected my notebook to database ,and had queried data using pycopg2 .
From that i am getting  3 columns 
1.created_at
2.lat 
3.long
From these lat long using python library H3 ,I am generating the hex_id  . .
So doing these i am getting the first table , and now i want to convert the 1st table  to the 2nd table provided ,

Comment: then you can use .groupby as @Ferris provided you an example.